# Read and print string - Assembly

Tags: string, assembly, x86, dos

I'm trying to create a program in assembly that read character by character, store it in an array and then print character by character. I know I can use interrupts to read and print strings, but want a own code to learn more.

The code is read, but do not know why it is not printing:

```
buff dw 0,0,0,0,0,0 
len equ 5 

mov ah, 1 
mov si, 0 

read: 
        
     mov al b.buff[si] 
     int 21h 
     inc si 
     cmp si, len 
     jl read 
     jmp print 
    
mov si, 0 
mov ah, 2 
   
print: 

     mov dl, b.buff [si] 
     int 21h 
     inc si
     cmp dl, 0 
     je end 
     jmp print
    
end:
```

Comment: And the question/problem is?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Is that the full program? It doesn't look like it would assemble (I can see at least one missing comma), and even if it does I doubt that it would run properly since you've put data in the code path. Also, your read loop never stores anything to `buff`.

Answer (score 1):

You've done quite a bit wrong. Don't feel bad - nobody is born knowing this stuff.

1) You don't tell us what assembler you're using. They're different! (looks like maybe Eric Isaacson's a86?)

2) Your buffer is declared "word"s, but you're using it as "byte"s. This probably won't do much harm.

3) Your buffer should probably be in a "data" section. You're going to try to execute your buffer. This could mess you up quite badly.

4) In your "read" loop, you put a zero from your buffer into `al`, then read a character (into `al`) and don't do anything with it! This is one of your two "big" problems.

5) At the end of your "read" loop, you jump over the two lines that reset `si` to zero and load 2 into `ah`... so you're still "reading", not printing (and in an unintended place in your buffer). This is the other "big" problem.

6) Your "print" loop expects a zero-terminated string. You don't explicitly zero-terminate your string at the end of your "read" loop. Since your buffer is pre-filled with zeros, this probably won't hurt, but you might want to do it.

7) You don't exit cleanly back to DOS (`int 21h/4Ch`)... unless "end" does this (depends on assembler?).

There may be more, but that should get you closer.